# Symmetrical many-to-many in Django admin screen

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a symmetrical many-to-many relationship in Django

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    connections = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

How do I see the connections (i.e. myappname_person_connections) table in the admin screen (not inline but as its own table)?

e.g. in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Person)
admin.site.register(???) # what to register for the connections?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M2M table is mapped to a model which is `Person.connections.through`, so you could use

```
admin.site.register(Person.connections.through)
```